# How can I make an alluvial graph using ggplot2 to show the results of cross tabulation from spss?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is my data:

```
 df <- structure(list(language = c("German", "German", "German", "German", 
"German", "German", "German", "German", "French", "French", "French", 
"French", "French", "French", "French", "French", "Italian", 
"Italian", "Italian", "Italian", "Italian", "Italian", "Italian", 
"Italian"), main_variable = c("d02a", "d02a", "d02a", "d02a", 
"d02a", "d02a", "d02a", "d02a", "d02a", "d02a", "d02a", "d02a", 
"d02a", "d02a", "d02a", "d02a", "d02a", "d02a", "d02a", "d02a", 
"d02a", "d02a", "d02a", "d02a"), combination1 = c("very_attached", 
"very_attached", "quite_attached", "quite_attached", "rather_only_sympathiser", 
"rather_only_sympathiser", "not_attached_to_a_party", "not_attached_to_a_party", 
"very_attached", "very_attached", "quite_attached", "quite_attached", 
"rather_only_sympathiser", "rather_only_sympathiser", "not_attached_to_a_party", 
"not_attached_to_a_party", "very_attached", "very_attached", 
"quite_attached", "quite_attached", "rather_only_sympathiser", 
"rather_only_sympathiser", "not_attached_to_a_party", "not_attached_to_a_party"
), combination2 = c("male", "female", "male", "female", "male", 
"female", "male", "female", "male", "female", "male", "female", 
"male", "female", "male", "female", "male", "female", "male", 
"female", "male", "female", "male", "female"), count = c(24L, 
23L, 56L, 42L, 78L, 75L, 183L, 218L, 4L, 2L, 12L, 22L, 24L, 33L, 
48L, 68L, 3L, 3L, 8L, 9L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 9L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-24L))
```

Is it possible to produce a chart like?

[image: this]

I would like to make a plot to show the results of a cross tabulation from spss like [this](http://www.unige.ch/ses/sococ/cl///spss/cmd/cross2.jpg) The dataframe has the stucture of this table but if there is any wrong in the transfer process to a data frame I can update it.

Comment: This type of graph is called an Alluvial Diagram. Check out the [`ggalluvial` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggalluvial/vignettes/ggalluvial.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something along these lines:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggalluvial)

df %>%
  ggplot(aes(y = count, axis1 = combination2, axis2 = language, axis3 = combination1)) +
  geom_alluvium(aes(fill = combination1), width = 0, knot.pos = 0, reverse = FALSE) +
  guides(fill = FALSE) +
  geom_stratum(width = 1/8, reverse = FALSE) +
  geom_text(stat = "stratum", aes(label = after_stat(stratum)), reverse = FALSE) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:3, labels = c("Sex", "Language", "attachment level")) +
  ggtitle("This is a title")
```

Comment: Hello @Jakub.Novotny, just a question, so you stack each layer using axis1, axis2 and so on?

Comment: thank you. Any idea for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62935926/windrose-for-open-and-close-prices