# Windrose for open and close prices

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some opening and closing prices for three stocks for 5 day periods.

```
df <- structure(list(stock = c("Google", "Google", "Google", "Google", 
"Google", "Google", "Google", "Google", "Google", "Google", "Yahoo", 
"Yahoo", "Yahoo", "Yahoo", "Yahoo", "Yahoo", "Yahoo", "Yahoo", 
"Yahoo", "Yahoo", "Amazon", "Amazon", "Amazon", "Amazon", "Amazon", 
"Amazon", "Amazon", "Amazon", "Amazon", "Amazon"), day = c("Monday", 
"Monday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Thurday", 
"Thurday", "Friday", "Friday", "Monday", "Monday", "Tuesday", 
"Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Thurday", "Thurday", "Friday", 
"Friday", "Monday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", 
"Wednesday", "Thurday", "Thurday", "Friday", "Friday"), startend = c("open", 
"close", "open", "close", "open", "close", "open", "close", "open", 
"close", "open", "close", "open", "close", "open", "close", "open", 
"close", "open", "close", "open", "close", "open", "close", "open", 
"close", "open", "close", "open", "close"), value = c(0.68, 0.67, 
0.16, 0.16, 0.28, 0.28, 0.16, 0.17, 0.36, 0.36, 0.74, 0.74, 0.13, 
0.13, 0.25, 0.25, 0.15, 0.15, 0.39, 0.39, 0.61, 0.6, 0.2, 0.21, 
0.3, 0.3, 0.21, 0.22, 0.37, 0.38)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-30L))
```

For a plot like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
data.in <- read.csv(file = "http://midcdmz.nrel.gov/apps/plot.pl?site=NWTC&start=20010824&edy=26&emo=3&eyr=2062&year=2013&month=1&day=1&endyear=2013&endmonth=12&endday=31&time=0&inst=21&inst=39&type=data&wrlevel=2&preset=0&first=3&math=0&second=-1&value=0.0&user=0&axis=1",
                    col.names = c("date","hr","ws.80","wd.80"))
p1 <- plot.windrose(spd = data.in$ws.80,
                   dir = data.in$wd.80)
```

How can it be ploted the stock data using the open and close variable for every day. More specifically, have six slices in the circle. The one half will have the open of the three stocks and have different color for every day of week.